# Regex to replace function in string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string

```
Apply the function K(i, x<=>k) for more info.
```

I want to convert `K(i, x<=>k)` to `K_{i}(x<>k)`, but the arguments inside the function `K` can vary, so I guess it is something like

```
string.replace(/\K\([.?],[.?]\)/g, 'K_{$1}($2)')
```

## Edit

Sorry for the vague explanation of what the arguments for K can be. I just thought the regex would be faster if it didn't specify what the arguments could be, but just had some placeholders.

The first argument of K can be only be numbers and letters and the second argument of K can be numbers, letters, spaces, ->, <->, [], <>, &, | and ~, and there can never be more than 2 arguments, so the pattern is always K(something, something).

The remaining string varies as well. So a string could also look like `I have a function K(i,a) and two other functions K(3,p&s |r) and K(f, ~g)`

Comment: and the problem is...?

Comment: Please give more examples if you want a regex that matches multiple cases.

Comment: *"arguments can vary"* ... that's pretty vague to be able to write a regex against

Comment: is the rest of the string always the same or does that vary too?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: What should be the output for `function K(3,p&s |r)` ?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. It should!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be something like that (you forgot to group args for the replace value):

`string.replace(/K\(([a-zA-Z0-9]+), ?(.+)\)/g, 'K_{$1}($2)')`